# Why my Magento admin area redirects to the old url?

Tags: magento2, admin, aws

Magento 2.3.1 installed on lightsail using the official bitnami AWS installer, if you go to the admin, it redirects back to the old website.  In the database **core_config_data** the URLs are correct.

I updated the domain name, I updated letsencrypt, I cleared and flushed Magento cache and restarted everything. Only the admin area is redirecting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run this step-by-step to check the possible things.

Run this command to get the Magerun2 to made the changes easier.

```
wget https://files.magerun.net/n98-magerun2.phar && chmod +x ./n98-magerun2.phar && alias n98="./n98-magerun2.phar"
```

Run this command to see if there is some additional base URL in your configurations that aren't correct.

```
n98 config:store:get %base_url%
n98 config:store:get %cookie_domain%
```

Regenerate all the static content again, reindex and flush the cache.

```
n98 maintenance:enable
n98 deploy:mode:set developer;
n98 setup:upgrade;
n98 setup:static-content:deploy -f;
n98 setup:di:compile;
n98 maintenance:disable;
n98 index:reindex;
n98 cache:flush;
```

Comment: if I run `n98 config:store:get %base_url%` or `n98 config:store:get %cookie_domain%` I get https://pastebin.com/W46Jgcxx

Comment: Running the above commands using magento command line tool and running `reindexer:reindex` fixed it, then I logged in to the admin area and changed the path to the static files